# How do you configure eth-lightwallet txutils example_usage.js to use a local eth node?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, wallets

The example code for eth-lightwallet that shows how to use it with the *hooked web3 provide*r can be configured to use the local node as follows:

```
var ethClient = "http://localhost:1111";
var web3 = new Web3();
var global_keystore;

function setWeb3Provider(keystore) {

    var web3Provider = new HookedWeb3Provider({
        host: ethClient,
        transaction_signer: keystore;
    });

    web3.setProvider(web3Provider);

}
```

The example_usage.js that demonstrates the use of txutils however does not show how the eth node can be set.  Can anyone advise?

example_usage.js starts...

```
// Example usage: Name Registry
// Create the contract, register the key 123, set the value 456

var lightwallet = require('../index.js')
var txutils = lightwallet.txutils
var signing = lightwallet.signing
var encryption = lightwallet.encryption
.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two different approaches. The first one, with [hooked web3 provider](https://github.com/ConsenSys/hooked-web3-provider/), it means that you use a normal Web3 provider but delegating the signing behavior to something else (in your example the keystore).

> The Hooked Web3 Provider is a normal HTTP Web3 provider that allows
>   you to "hook in" an external transaction signer that can be used to
>   sign transactions for accounts not managed by the Ethereum client
>   (i.e., aren't managed by geth). An example transaction signer might be
>   an external program or device that manages its own accounts and
>   private keys. Together, the transaction signer and the web3 provider
>   will use the Ethereum client to place signed transactions on the
>   network.

txutils libray on the contrary is useful especially when you want to use a [*classic* web3 provider](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API). In this case, you can prepare and sign the transaction with txutils, reference Web3 and attach to the node [as usual](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#adding-web3)

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

and then you can use the [web3.eth.sendRawTransaction method](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction)

```
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signedTransactionData [, callback])
```

to send the txns to the network.